# How to call Java method from JAR which is deployed on Weblogic server from the database procedure

Tags: java, plsql, jar, weblogic, java-deployment-toolkit

I have deployed JAR file in the WebLogic server and the requirement is i want to call some of the method from the deployed code from the PL/SQL, So is there any way available to achieve this requirement?

How to call Java method from JAR which is deployed on WebLogic server from the database procedure

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.